# siunitx tables and commands between columns

Tags: tables, spacing, siunitx

I'd like to add parenthesis around some columns in a table, using the `siunitx` package. I'm using the `>` and `<` column specifiers, and they seem to work... except in the last column, where some additional space is inserted. This is sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\sisetup{table-format = 1.2,table-auto-round = true}

\begin{tabular}
  {l*{4}{S@{~}
         >{{(}}
         S[table-format=1.1,
           table-figures-exponent=1,table-sign-exponent=true,
           scientific-notation=true,
           table-space-text-pre=(,table-space-text-post=)]
         <{{)}}
        }
  }
A & 1.234&0.987e-4  & 4.567&0.654e-5  \\
B & 2.345&0.876e-3  & 5.678&0.543e-3  \\
C & 3.456&0.765     & 6.789&0.432     \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image]

As you can see, there's an unwanted space before the closing parenthesis in the second column.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way of inserting the parentheses (or anything else)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manual mentions that there can be some issues with the very last cell. The usual way around this is to use the TeX `\cr` primitive to end the cell:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\sisetup{table-format = 1.2,table-auto-round = true}

\begin{tabular}
  {l*{2}{S@{~}
         >{{(}}
         S[table-format=1.1e-1,
           scientific-notation=true,
           table-space-text-pre=(,table-space-text-post=)]
         <{{)}}
        }
  }
A & 1.234&0.987e-4  & 4.567&0.654e-5  \cr
B & 2.345&0.876e-3  & 5.678&0.543e-3  \cr
C & 3.456&0.765     & 6.789&0.432     \cr
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

(I've tided up your `table-format` a bit, too.)

Comment: Thanks, that's section "7.13 Adding items after the last column of a tabular", for the record, I see it now. Thanks for the `table-format` hint too.

Comment: Adding a fake column?